# Oracle Apex change Checksum Error to 404 Page Not Found

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, apex, oracle-apps

The goal is whenever the user add additional character at the end of the URL, they will be redirected to 404 not found page. But instead, checksum error is appearing. take a look at this sample: Is there a way to modify this? Or any set up need to adjust?

Expected:

[image]

Current error:

[image]

Comment: check the debug id ( you have the number there ) in Monitor activity --> by view. Add the code of the item you have specified the checksum

Comment: Yes. But my goal is, instead of returning checksum error, it will be redirected to a 404 not found error. The above mentioned error was because, after the success process, I manipulated and added additional character at the end of the URL. My goal is when user do that, they will be prompted a 404 Not Found instead of checksum.

Comment: have you try to use `PREPARE_URL` ?

Comment: HHmmm, not yet. But where can I place it? Can you guide me on how it will be done?